# Bash not splitting a string into an array past the first index

Tags: arrays, string, bash, split

I have a variable thats set to all sub directories in my current working dir, I did this by doing

```
directories=` ls -d -- */`
```

This returns the following to me "d1/ d2/" and I want to split this into an array by whitespace so I run the following code I found on stack overflow that seems to work for others but isn't working for me. The code is

```
IFS=' ' read -ra grArray <<< "$directories"
```

now this should split my string into two indices grArray[0] and grArray[1] which should be "d1/" and "d2/" respectively, but when I try to print both indices of the array I get "d1/" and the second array comes up as " "

If someone could point out what I'm missing here I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `ls` like this; just use a glob to set the array directly:

```
directories=( */ )
```

Comment: I was going to do `grArray=( */ )`, but you beat me to it `:)`

Comment: So that is just returning /d1 for me it doesn't return both the sub directories.

Comment: Yes, it does. You are probably doing something like `echo "$directories"` instead of the correct expansion `echo "${directories[@]}"`.

Comment: ah you're right, my mistake. it's working as it should now thank you